# Yii2 authentication

Tags: php, yii2

I'm modifying the `User.php` model from the basic installation.

This is what I have now:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{

    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param  string      $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param  string  $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->password === \Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }
}
```

The `LoginForm.php` is calling it in:

```
public function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
        $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
    }

    return $this->_user;
}
```

The problem I have is, when the program reaches `validatePassword` of `User.php`, `$this->password` is always `null` and validation fails.

I am sure that the record is found as I can see the values in `LoginForm.php's $this->_user`. Else it'll be `null` when I tried to find some random user.

How can I populate `User.php's $this->password` with the one found in the static function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have do define attributes ('id', 'username', 'password') that are already stored in User db table. As a matter of fact you are redefining your database values with null here.

Also change `validatePassword` to

```
/**
 * Validates password
 *
 * @param  string  $password password to validate
 * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
 */
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return \Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I did try to remove the declaration, but after removing them, then `$this->password` doesn't exists. Oh wait. It does exist. I'll do more test first.

Comment: Cool. That was one of the problem. The other was me using the wrong validation method. Have updated your answer to include that.